# Axios get URL not working after concatenation

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am having a problem using Axios with node js. Here is my code

`let callResult = await axios.get(urlData, config)`

Where config is

```
let config = {
        headers: {
            'X-Token': token
        }
    };
```

And the urlData is

```
let urlData = 'https://api.regulaforensics.com/webapi/Transaction2/GetTransactionResultJson?transactionId=<IDVariable>&resultType=15'
```

I am trying to add my IDVariable to the URL but it does not work. If I take the variable and put it directly in the URL I get a response.

I have also tried this

```
let config = {
        headers: {
            'X-Token': token
        },
        params: {
         transactionId: IDVariable,
         resultType: 15
    }};
```

And this

```
let querys = querystring.stringify({ transactionId: keyId, resultType: 15 })
let path = 'https://api.regulaforensics.com/webapi/Transaction2/GetTransactionResultJson?'
```

```
let urlData = path.concat("", querys)
```

This is the complete URL

```
https://api.regulaforensics.com/webapi/Transaction2/GetTransactionResultJson?transactionId=05cc6ccc-3ae6-4185-b2c9-1e1aba01d705&resultType=15
```

[When using {params: } or concatenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPBGG.png)

[When putting the whole URL. As the URL I pasted above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMwQS.png)

[This is my whole function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3kCv.png)

Comment: What's the issue? Is an error being returned?

Comment: I want to use those two params transactionId and resultType. What I get is body: null

Comment: can you try in postman with same header and params?

Comment: Hey Jose, are you trying to use Axios inside the Node.js server? If so you can't use axios, you need to use XMLHTTPRequest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some parameters as a query string you can use the following syntax for the `GET` request:

```
axios.get('/user', { params: { ID: 12345 } });
```

Tath will be translated in the following request:

```
/user?ID=12345
```

As explained in the documentation here: https://github.com/axios/axios#note-commonjs-usage

**Note**

You don't need to add the `?` char at the end of URL and you don't need to have the parameters in the URL, so the part `?transactionId=<IDVariable>&resultType=15` must be removed

Comment: I had tried that with my header

{
        headers: {
            'X-Token': token
        },
        params: {
         transactionId: IDVariable,
         resultType: 15
    }}
But I still getting body: null in my response

Comment: Do you have any console warning or some network error? Are you sure that the header is the right one?

Comment: Note also that, for this API, you need to pass the `Accept: application/json` header.

Comment: I only get the error when trying to use {params: <ParamsGoHere>} or when I try to concatenate the IDVariable. When I put the whole URL I get a successful response

Comment: Can you please share the request URL that you can find in the `network` tab of your browser developer tools? (hide data you don't want to share with us)

Comment: I  modified my question with images

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
I am calling a service first and the response of that service is the key I need for the second service.
The solution was to just put a sleep() between those two services.

Thanks you for your response, guys!